# SQL Server : SELECT CASE return NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a `SELECT` in which if the `CurrencyCode` is = '', then I would like the result to be return as `NULL`.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Currency (CurrencyCode, CurrencyName)
    SELECT 
        CurrencyCode,
        CASE
            WHEN CurrencyCode = ''
              THEN NULL
        END
    FROM Contract
```

Can it be done?

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: Your code looks fine - isn't it working?

Comment: Could be even shorter: `select currencycode, nullif(currencycode, '') from contract`

Comment: Your code is not perfect as if the `currencyCode` is not '' ,it would not display anythings.

Comment: Thank all. I've gotten what I want using the NULLIF. Previously, the error which I got is "None of the result expressions in a CASE specification can be NULL."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities either you use `CASE WHE... THEN... ELSE... END` OR `NULLIF`

```
SELECT CurrencyCode,
NULLIF(CurrencyCode,''),
CASE
    WHEN CurrencyCode = ''
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CurrencyCode
END
FROM Contract
```